# c# mongdb insert subDocument to subDocument

Tags: c#, mongodb

[image]

how can insert new subdocument to Offer, use this code can not update, the error message:MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: 'Element name 'Courses' is not valid'.'

```
var builder1 = Builders<Dept_Entity>.Filter;
                var filter11 = builder1.Eq(x=>x.DeptID,"IS");
                var documnt = new BsonDocument
                {
                    {  "Courses",new BsonArray
                        {
                             new BsonDocument
                             {
                                {"CourseID",txt_courseID.Text},
                                {"Title",txt_title.Text},
                                {"Level",Int32.Parse(txt_level.Text)},
                                 {"Offer", new BsonArray
                                     {
                                         new BsonDocument
                                         {
                                             { "DeptID",txt_Year.Text },
                                             { "CourseID",txt_courseID.Text},
                                             {"Year",txt_Year.Text},
                                             {"AvailablePlaces",txt_availableplaces.Text },
                                             {"ClassSize",txt_classszie.Text }
                                         }
                                     }

                                 }
                             }
                        }
                    }
                };
                collection1.UpdateOne(filter11, documnt);
```

the error message
[image]